# How to read a barcode from an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, image-processing, barcode

I'm seeking a library, technique or advice on how to read an [EAN-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAN-13) barcode from an image (including [ISBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN#EAN_format_used_in_barcodes.2C_and_upgrading),and [ISSN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISSN) encodings).
The image would come from a mobile phone or webcam, so resolution may be quite poor and not well aligned.

I'm specifically interested in something that could be used from ruby on rails, but answers for other languages are welcome. Open Source solutions preferred.

Leading solutions to date:

1. [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) (previously known as Zebra - h/t @bgbg, @Natim) - implemented in C with interfaces for Python, Perl, and C++
2. [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) (h/t @codr) - implemented in Java (J2SE and Android) with other modules/ports in varying states of development (JavaME, C#, C++, JRuby, RIM, iPhone/Objective C)

Comment: keep us posted with your experiences with zebra :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This project might be what you're looking for: [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Answer (score 6):

The zebra barcode reader (http://zebra.sourceforge.net/) is a small, layered bar code scanning and decoding library implemented in C (C++ wrappers are also provided). It supports many popular symbologies (types of barcodes), including EAN-13.  However, I'm not aware about any Ruby bindings. The library is available under the GPL

Comment: @bgbg good tip, thanks. looks promising even though not for ruby

Comment: Doesn't exists anymore. Look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/

Comment: Thanks @Natim. Just to clarify for all, I discovered ZBar is actually the Zebra project after a name change (done "..for compelling reasons..";-)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this if it's to allow your site's visitors to scan stuff, I think it's embeddable in your own site, but I've never used it : http://en.barcodepedia.com/

Comment: I see a data api is in the roadmap http://en.barcodepedia.com/about. One to watch ... seems like it could be an ideal solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Softek](http://www.softeksoftware.co.uk/index.html) library.

Very pleased with the results.