# How to read a EAN-13 bar-code from an image in C?

Tags: c, opencv, barcode, barcode-scanner

I would like to read a EAN-13 bar-code from an image in C.
I found [the OpenCV library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) that should help me to compute the image as well as [an article about an iPhone App that can read Sudoku.](http://sudokugrab.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html)

But in an other hand, I found [an opensource library to read DataMatrix bar-code](http://www.libdmtx.org/).

I would like to join an existing OpenSource project about reading bar-code instead of starting one, since I am sure that some people already worked on this.

Do you have an idea of were to start and what to use to read EAN-13 barcode in C ?

Comment: Seams that this question is quite similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113571/how-to-read-a-barcode-from-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project looks quite close to what I am looking for : http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/